# Comparing current URL with result of createURL in Yii

Tags: yii

I need to compare the current url with a url obtained from `createURL`.

Keep in mind that `createURL` can be called like this:

```
array('mycontroller/mypage', 'view'=>'myviewonmypage')
```

and also keep in mind that this can (and will) return a URL matching the rewrite rules from Yii's config.

So, my question is: How can I check if the current URL is matching a URL create with `createURL`.

I have tried

```
Yii::app()->getController()->getRoute()
```

but this will return only the controller and the action part, so it won't match as the view part is ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare using $_SERVER variable like this:

```
if(Yii::app()->createUrl('test/test') == $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']){
               echo "YES!";
           }
```

Comment: Are you sure this will work with reqrite URLs? (Apacha and IIS).